# Use multiple child containers for SVG rendering?

Tags: javascript, svg, containers, element

Currently when I create my SVG document I use a single "canvas" svg object like this:

```
<svg id="svgCanvas" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
   xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
```

and then I refer to it like this:

```
var svgCanvas = document.getElementById( "svgCanvas" );
```

All the SVG objects are then added as children to this object. For example, if I create a line, I do it like this:

```
    function createLine( id, x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width ){
        var svgCanvas = document.getElementById( "svgCanvas" );
        var line  = document.createElementNS( svgNS, "line" );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "id", id );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "x1", x1 );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "y1", y1 );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "x2", x2 );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "y2", y2 );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "stroke", color );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "stroke-width", width );
        svgCanvas.appendChild( line );
    }
```

The problem is that my drawings have both static and dynamic elements. Some things move around, get deleted and redrawn, change shape, etc. Other things are static and stay the same way permanently.

When I clear my canvas, I do not want to delete these permanent objects, I just want to delete the changeable objects. So, ideally I would like to have some kind of container that is a child of the svg object (svgCanvas) which contains the dynamic objects only, so that when I do a clear I can just iterate that container and delete its children, and leave the static objects which are children of the main svgCanvas the way they are.

Is there any way to make a such a "container" that is a child object of svgCanvas and still renders all the objects in the container on the svg?

Also, can I remove all these items just by removing the container and not need to iterate through every object in the container and remove them individually?

*** UPDATE ***

I have added a group as follows:

```
    function initialize(){
        svgCanvas = document.getElementById( "svgCanvas" )
        gDynamic  = document.createElementNS( svgNS, "g" );
        gDynamic.setAttribute( "id", "DynamicGroup" );
        svgCanvas.appendChild( gDynamic );
    }
```

However, after doing this, any objects added to svgCanvas appear, but none of the objects in the child group appear.

Answer (score 1):

Both `<g>` and `<svg>` elements both acts as containers for other elements. Removing them from a document will remove all their children too.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use groups.  And you will want to modify your element creation functions so that you can pass in which parent element they should be added to.

```
var svgCanvas = document.getElementById( "svgCanvas" );

// Create a group
var svgGroup = createGroup(svgCanvas, "myGroupId");
// Add a line to the group
createLine(svgGroup, ...etc...);

// do stuff

// Done with group, so remove it, and its children
svgGroup.parentNode.removeChild(svgGroup);


function createLine( parent, id, x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width ) {
    var line  = document.createElementNS( svgNS, "line" );
    line.setAttribute( "id", id );
    line.setAttribute( "x1", x1 );
    line.setAttribute( "y1", y1 );
    line.setAttribute( "x2", x2 );
    line.setAttribute( "y2", y2 );
    line.setAttribute( "stroke", color );
    line.setAttribute( "stroke-width", width );
    parent.appendChild( line );
}

function createGroup( parent , id ) {
    var group  = document.createElementNS( svgNS, "g" );
    group.setAttribute( "id", id );
    parent.appendChild( group );
}
```

Comment: I have done something similar to this (see code in question), but none of the objects in the dynamic group appear, only the main svgCanvas children appear.

Comment: How are you adding elements to the group?  Can we see that code?  In fact, you should create a working code snippet or fiddle so we can see the whole thing working.